# Slight Increase in Size of Java 3D Array Causes Huge Increase in Allocation Time

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, time

In Java, creating a 3D array as `double[][][] testArray = new double[5][1500000][2];` (after increasing the heap size) runs in about 2 seconds on my machine. However, increasing the second dimension by a factor of ten, from 1,500,000 to 15,000,000, causes a huge increase in allocation time; I let the program run on my machine for 45 minutes, and it did not terminate. Also, creating an array as `double[] testArray = new double[150000000]`, which should contain the same number of doubles as the large 3D array, runs in under a second. Why does increasing the 2nd dimension by a factor of ten cause such a huge increase in allocation time? (A program that I am writing requires that I create a 3D array of size `[5][15000000][2]`.)

Comment: A ten-fold increase in size from 1.5 million to 15 million is a large increase rather than a slight increase. The larger size has 150 million elements at 8 bytes per element this is 1.2 billion bytes. You probably need to increase the size of the heap.

Comment: @NomadMaker Even though I never received a memory error, increasing the heap size did the trick. Thank you.

Comment: @NomadMaker+ `double [5][15_000_000][2]` is 1.2G for the user data, but including object headers and references, at least on all Oracle JVMs I have j7-13, uses 2.7G total -- and since that must all fit in 'old' space, the total _heap_ must be larger yet, per my testing about 3.5G or `-Xms3500m`. But if I make it big(ger) enough to exceed _physical_ memory available, then it swaps which also kills performance.